# Is suffixing a UUID derived DICOM UID standard conform?

Tags: standards, uuid, dicom, uid

*Additional [discussion on the comp.protocols.dicom google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.protocols.dicom/VzoyHULHwgU).*

---

Specific example:

Given that instance UIDs are derived from UUIDs as described in [PS3.5 B.2](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_B.2.html).

For example given the following DICOM instance UID:

```
2.25.329800735698586629295641978511506172918
```

**Is it standard conform to suffix that UID by adding additional components?**

```
2.25.329800735698586629295641978511506172918.1, 
2.25.329800735698586629295641978511506172918.2, 
...
```

---

Concern:

From reading the standard, I somehow got the impression that the DICOM standard defines this form of UID only as valid if it only consists of the `2.25` prefix and the decimal representation of a valid UUID - and nothing more:

> [ISO/IEC 9834-8](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/chapter_2.html#biblio_ISOIEC9834-8) / [ITU-T X.667](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/chapter_2.html#biblio_ITU-T_X.667) defines a method by which a UID may
>   be constructed from the root "2.25." followed by a decimal
>   representation of a Universally Unique Identifier (UUID). That decimal
>   representation treats the 128 bit UUID as an integer, and may thus be
>   up to 39 digits long (leading zeros must be suppressed).

It does not explicitly say if there can be a suffix or not.

It has a max length of 5 + 39 characters and therefore has still some room until the 64 character limit of UIDs.

**Do all rules from [PS3.5 9.1](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/chapter_9.html) still apply to the UID definition of [PS3.5 B.2](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_B.2.html) just with a fixed root? Or is [PS3.5 B.2](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_B.2.html) an independent definition?**

---

Additional information on UUID derived UIDs:

As far as I understand the DICOM standard, [PS3.5 B.2](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_B.2.html) was added 2012 and is an exception to the normal UID definition defined by [PS3.5 9.1](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/chapter_9.html) and [PS3.5 B.1](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/chapter_B.html).
It does not require an organisation root prefix. Instead it uses the general prefix [2.25](http://www.oid-info.com/get/2.25) for all instance UIDs which are derived from UUIDs.
Important to note here, that it should only be used for instance UIDs.
See:

> A UUID derived UID may be appropriate for dynamically created UIDs,
>   such as SOP Instance UIDs, but is usually not appropriate for UIDs
>   determined during application software design, such as private SOP
>   Class or Transfer Syntax UIDs, or Implementation Class UIDs.

As an additional pointer to this exception ([source](https://www.dclunie.com/medical-image-faq/html/part2.html)):

> Another approach to generating UIDs that does not require obtaining
>   one's own root prefix can take advantage of a standard prefix
>   established for using a Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) [...] in
>   essence it involves converting the normal hyphenated hexadecimal
>   string form of a UUID into a single large decimal number and appending
>   it to the prefix "2.25."

Comment: I'm a bit curious why you only have one UUID and why your UIDs need to be connected to it. Wouldn't it be easier to just get your own UID prefix (from [here](https://www.medicalconnections.co.uk/FreeUID/) for example) and use that?

Comment: Your statement that UUID derived UIDs should only be used for instance UIDs is incorrect. These UIDs can of course also be used as Series UID, Study UID, etc.

The purpose of the remark in the DICOM standard that it is not appropriate to use  UUID derived UIDs during software design is the fact that organisation root UIDs are easier to understand for humans and to track back to the organization that created them. For example the prefix 1.2.840.10008. gives a hint that that this UID is defined by DICOM standard itself. Computer systems only require that an UID is unique, nothing more.

Comment: @VictorDerks You probably misinterpret was I wrote. With instance UID I'm not only referring to SOP instance UIDs but also to Series instance UIDs, Study instance UIDs, ... and other instance UIDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely not.

You cannot add anything as a suffix to 2.25 + UUID.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's conformant to modify an existing UUID derived UID, and even if it were that it'd be a bad idea to do so. The expectation is that an UID with the `2.25.` prefix is followed by a component value that can be coverted to a UUID.

The use of `2.25.` + UUID is a [registered OID](http://www.oid-info.com/get/2.25).

Comment: With adding an additional component to the end, the expectation that the component following `2.25.` is derived from a UUID is still valid.

Comment: For reference: the [related question in Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.protocols.dicom/VzoyHULHwgU) (from the comments in the deleted answer).